# Highlight groups of table columns

Tags: html, css, html-table, datagridviewcolumn

I have a column for which I need to highlight adjacent columns.

For the below [**example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/xameeramir/vvvtw2sc/):

```html
<table border="1" style="width:100%;">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Number</th>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Points</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Eve</td>
      <td>Jackson</td>
      <td>94</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>Doe</td>
      <td>80</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Adam</td>
      <td>Johnson</td>
      <td>67</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I need to show an **extra border** around the below pairs of columns

- `Number` and `First Name`
- `Last Name` and `Points`

How do I do it?

Any suggestions, kind folks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using `:nth-child` selector.

```css
tr:first-child th:nth-child(1), tr:first-child th:nth-child(2){
   border: 1px solid red;
   border-bottom: 0;
}

tr td:nth-child(1), tr td:nth-child(2){
   border-left: 1px solid red;
   border-right: 1px solid red;
}

tr:last-child td:nth-child(1), tr:last-child td:nth-child(2){
   border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}

tr:first-child th:nth-child(3), tr:first-child th:nth-child(4){
   border: 1px solid green;
   border-bottom: 0;
}

tr td:nth-child(3), tr td:nth-child(4){
   border-left: 1px solid green;
   border-right: 1px solid green;
}

tr:last-child td:nth-child(3), tr:last-child td:nth-child(4){
   border-bottom: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<table border="1" style="width:100%;">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Number</th>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Points</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Eve</td>
      <td>Jackson</td>
      <td>94</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>Doe</td>
      <td>80</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Adam</td>
      <td>Johnson</td>
      <td>67</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Can I +1 it please?

Comment: @student What do you mean? If you can upvote? Sure, feel free to do it if it has helped to you :)

Comment: I have crossed the daily limit :( I'll do it tomorrow :) Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with :nth-child

```html
<style type="text/css" scoped>
   table td:nth-child(odd) {
       border-left:red 1px solid;
   }
   table td:nth-child(even) {
       border-right:red 1px solid;
   }
</style>

<table border="1" style="width:100%;">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Number</th>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Points</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Eve</td>
      <td>Jackson</td>
      <td>94</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>Doe</td>
      <td>80</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Adam</td>
      <td>Johnson</td>
      <td>67</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```